# I cannot hear Google maps voice after update

Tags: google-maps

After the last update, I cannot hear Google Maps voice while navigating. I only get a nerve breaking bell like sound every time I am close to a turn. I cannot see anything obvious in the settings on how to fix that.

Why did this happen and what can I do to change it back to voice navigation?

My OS is android 6.0 (LG G4 device)

Comment: Have you tried deleting data (you will lose off line maps) and cache of  maps? It may help

Comment: @beeshyams how can I do that?

Comment: Settings > Apps > click on maps > long press on Storage > clear data and cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found why this was happening. I suppose that after an update voice through bluetooth option was selected automatically. Since I didn't have (never had actually) any bluetooth device, no voice could be heard.

Fixed this by going to google maps settings and deselecting voice through bluetooth option.

hope this helps others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem - Google Maps suddenly no longer gave driving instructions via voice. In my case the problem was fixed by going to Settings (Android Settings, not Google Maps Settings) - Sounds and Vibrations - Volume. The volume for Media was set to zero, I have no idea how that happened. Anyway, after pushing it up to about 70% then all was well again.

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed this by deleting Google Maps updates.  It's the updates that are the problem apparently.  Without the updates I get sound when I click on the microphone icon in the top banner, but with the updates installed all that happens when I do that is that a drop down window shows some distances and nothing turns the sound on.  So delete the updates and then set Google Play not to update the program.  Wish Google would fix this because the updates would probably be helpful if not for this bug.

Answer (score 0):

First check with Aux or Bluetooth, if you are having same issues

Second, go to Settings - System – Language and input – Text-to-speech options. Then under the Preferred text-to-speech engine, check if certain language is selected; if not, select Language. Clear cache and check again.

Comment: What do you mean by 'check with Aux or Bluetooth, if you are having same issues'? I don't use blootooth.

Comment: This happened to be once on my asus zenfone and turned out to be problem device speaker (h/w issue). I found by playing music/sound on Bluetooth speakers and was not setting issue.. So, just in case.

Comment: The thing is that I can hear the bell sounds. Just no voice. That's why I think it is a settings problem after the update.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn down the radio volume when the satnav is giving instructions you actually turn of the satnav volume.
Wait to you think the satnav is giving instructions and turn up the volume. The voice should then return.
Therefore, don’t reduce radio volume when satnav is talking.